# Submenu does not work with IE 7

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer-7

http://jsbin.com/asafow/4/edit#preview

I have this menu and it works fine in FF, IE8/9 Chrome.
But it does not work on IE7  when I hover over 'Other Work'.

I am wondering if anyone gives me advice how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not working at all in IE9 (at least for me); no menu displays. IE8, the menu does show up (doesn't match what Firefox 9 shows). IE7, you see the menu, but it's got a lot of space between each menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Submenus does not work on IE7 because of CSS.
The element container should have the property:

```
z-index:10; /* while 10 is any number */
```

I experienced such this bug before and i fixed it with this css.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with that:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check code you have written css

```
#nav li:hover{
    background: #01291e url('http://www.cecilieokada.com/assets/images/cecilie/hover.png') no-repeat 50% 33px;
    line-height: 47px;
}
```

this line height causing issue if you remove line-height: 47px; then it will work fine in IE7. if you only want to remove it for IE7 then you may use conditional comment as explained in below link

http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/